# Countable topological basis with some inclusion properties

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, descriptive-set-theory

Given a second countable topological space $(X,\tau)$, I want a countable basis $\mathcal{B}$ with the following properties: \begin{align}&\forall B \in \mathcal{B} \text{ the set } \{B' \in \mathcal{B} \mid B \subseteq B'\} \text{ is finite} \tag{1}\\ &\forall B \in \mathcal{B} \text{ the set } \{B' \in \mathcal{B} \mid B \subseteq B'\} \text{ is well-founded wrt } \supseteq \tag{2}\end{align}
my questions are:

1. Is there a name for such a properties ?
2. Can we find both kinds of basis for every second countable space?
3. Otherwise, is there a counterexample?
4. Are there other well-known topological properties of the space that guarantee the existence of such basis (or that is equivalent to the existence of such a basis)?

Thanks!

EDIT: Note that condition (2) is (strictly?) weaker than (1). Indeed condition (2) says that there are no infinite increasing wrt $\subseteq$ sequences of elements of the basis.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Well $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology satisfies (1)...

Comment: Not for the standard countable base...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes sure, but the usual topology admits a basis that satisfies (1)

Comment: The second is much harder to try to achieve. It will fail in any Hausdorff second countable space I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Mmm but (1) implies (2), actually (2) is weaker (strictly?) than (1). Condition (2) says that there are no infinite sequences of elements of the basis strictly increasing wrt $\subseteq$ (or decreasing wrt $\supseteq$ as I wrote).

Comment: Your wellfoundedness goes the other way. So that’s doable then ( but pointless).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Why pointless? Such wellfoundedness condition gives you an ordinal rank of the elements of the basis... It allows for example to prove things by transfinite induction on the elements of the basis.

Comment: It’s unclear what we could use such a base for. There is much more study of closed bases with lattice properties (compactification theory )

Answer (score 1):

Look at the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $[0,1)$ generated by the basis $[0,q)$.

Any countable basis $B$ of $\mathcal{T}$ will not satisfy your first criterion. Or your second criterion.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about question 4?

Comment: If I knew the answer to that, I'd publish a paper on it :)

Comment: I suspect that necessary conditions will be of greater interest than sufficient conditions